# Calculadora de IP em JS

Tags: javascript, ip

Olá. Preciso desenvolver uma calculadora de rede em JavaScript que descubra o endereço de broadcast e o endereço de rede a partir do endereço de IP (IPv4) e máscara da rede. Mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso. Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Pergunta [XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy)?

Comment: IPv4 apenas ou IPv6 também?

Answer (score 2):

Segue o código que fiz. Só funciona para IPv4:

```js
function IPv4(input) {

    // Se o input já for um IPv4, não cria um objeto novo.
    if (input instanceof IPv4) return input;

    // Se o "new" tiver sido omitido, faz a chamada com ele.
    if (!(this instanceof IPv4)) return new IPv4(input);

    // Se o input for uma string, a separa em partes.
    if (typeof input === "string") {
        var partes = input.split(".");
        return new IPv4(partes);
    }

    // Se o input não for nem string, nem array e nem um outro IPv4, então desiste.
    if (!(input instanceof Array)) {
        throw "IPv4 inválido (tentativa de construir com entrada de tipo não-reconhecido): '" + input.join(".") + "'.";
    }

    // Neste ponto, o input só pode ser um array. Se não tiver exatamente quatro elementos, é mal-formado.
    if (input.length !== 4) {
        throw "IPv4 inválido (não tem quatro partes): '" + input.join(".") + "'.";
    }

    // Separa os quatro elementos do array e garante que sejam números.
    var m1, m2, m3, m4;
    try {
        var m1 = parseInt(input[0], 10);
        var m2 = parseInt(input[1], 10);
        var m3 = parseInt(input[2], 10);
        var m4 = parseInt(input[3], 10);
    } catch (e) {
        throw "IPv4 inválido (valores não numéricos): '" + input.join(".") + "'.";
    }

    // O parseInt é muito leniente quanto a textos mal-formados. Aqui verificamos se esse foi o caso.
    if ("" + m1 !== "" + input[0] || "" + m2 !== "" + input[1] || "" + m3 !== "" + input[2] || "" + m4 !== "" + input[3]) {
        throw "IPv4 inválido (partes com trechos não reconhecidos): '" + input.join(".") + "'.";
    }

    // Verifica se todos os valores estão na faixa correta.
    if (m1 < 0 || m1 > 255 || m2 < 0 || m2 > 255 || m3 < 0 || m3 > 255 || m4 < 0 || m4 > 255) {
        throw "IPv4 inválido (valores fora da faixa 0-255): '" + input.join(".") + "'.";
    }

    this.partes = function() {
        return [m1, m2, m3, m4];
    };

    this.and = function(outro) {
        var p2 = outro.partes();
        return new IPv4([m1 & p2[0], m2 & p2[1], m3 & p2[2], m4 & p2[3]]);
    };

    this.or = function(outro) {
        var p2 = outro.partes();
        return new IPv4([m1 | p2[0], m2 | p2[1], m3 | p2[2], m4 | p2[3]]);
    };

    this.not = function() {
        return new IPv4([~m1 & 0xFF, ~m2 & 0xFF, ~m3 & 0xFF, ~m4 & 0xFF]);
    };

    this.toString = function() {
        return m1 + "." + m2 + "." + m3 + "." + m4;
    };

    this.mascarar = function(mascara) {
        mascara = IPv4(mascara);

        return {
            rede: this.and(mascara),
            broadcast: this.or(mascara.not())
        };
    };
}

document.getElementById("botaoCalcular").onclick = function() {
    var ip = document.getElementById("ip").value;
    var mascara = document.getElementById("mascara").value;

    try {
        calculado = IPv4(ip).mascarar(mascara);
        document.getElementById("rede").value = calculado.rede;
        document.getElementById("broadcast").value = calculado.broadcast;
        document.getElementById("erro").innerHTML = "";
    } catch (e) {
        document.getElementById("rede").value = "Erro!";
        document.getElementById("broadcast").value = "Erro!";
        document.getElementById("erro").innerHTML = e;
    }
};
```

```html
<p>
    Entre com o endereço IPv4: <input type="text" id="ip" value="192.168.28.70" />
</p>
<p>
    Entre com a máscara de rede: <input type="text" id="mascara" value="255.255.255.0" />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="button" id="botaoCalcular" value="Calcular" />
</p>
<p>
    Endereço de rede: <input type="text" id="rede" value="" readonly />
</p>
<p>
    Endereço de broadcast: <input type="text" id="broadcast" value="" readonly />
</p>
<p id="erro"></p>
```

Clique no botão azul "<kbd>Executar</kbd>" acima para testar e brincar.

A função `IPv4` cria um objeto que representa um endereço IPv4. Boa parte do seu código é para validar se o seu parâmetro (uma string ou um array) é bem formado e para fazer o parse dele, separando os quatro números do IPv4 (os comentários do código explicam cada um dos passos desse processo).

O IPv4 é na verdade um conjunto de 32 bits representado em quatro números de 8 bits cada. O cálculo do endereço de rede e do endereço de broadcast é obtido ao combinar os bits correspondentes do endereço IP com o da máscara de rede, sendo cada posição independente das demais. Ou seja, o cálculo do bit 12 (por exemplo) do endereço de rede e do broadcast é totalmente independente do cálculo feito com o bit 11 ou com o 13 ou com qualquer outro bit.

No javascript, temos os operadores bitwise `&`, `|` e `~` para fazer o `E`, `OU` e `NÃO` bit-a-bit. Eles são usados nos métodos `and`, `or` e `not` do objeto `IPv4`.

O endereço de rede é obtido com a fórmula `IP AND MASCARA`, enquanto que o endereço de broadcast é o `IP OR NOT MASCARA`, operações essas realizadas bit-a-bit. O método `mascarar` é a que invoca essas operações no endereço IP, produzindo ambos os resultados.

Esse código segue o [padrão MVC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC). A função `IPv4` é o modelo. O HTML é a visão. O javascript que está após a função `IPv4` manipulando o `document` e interligando o modelo e a visão é o controlador.